# Do while loop on recordset keeps running while the total records are way less

Tags: sql-server, loops, asp-classic, recordset

IO got a real weird problem in my asp classic page. I am generating a schedule of days off for employees. When I tested it it seemed to work fine. Though with another option I could go a week back and forth and when I went 3 weeks back the loop keeps getting looping on one single record.

So I wanted to check where the problem was by doing a count on the recordset after the SQL execution.

For some reason though, the do while loop keeps looping. I did a print count in the do while to see how many records it finds and now it is already on 508 000 !

So in my t-sql server (2012) I did the EXACT same query and here it only results in 953 records...

So obviously tghere goes something wrong in the loop.

Here is the code I am using:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [qrySnipperKalender_B] WHERE [snipperdag] >= "& szStart &" AND [snipperdag]<= "& szEnd &" ORDER BY [FunctieGroep], [Relatienaam], [Datum] ASC"


    response.write(strSQL & "<br> <br>")

    set rst=con_sql.execute(strSQL)
    CountCheck = 0


    Do until rst.EOF or rst.BOF
        response.write("Count is: " & CountCheck & "<br>")

        CountCheck = CountCheck + 1
    Loop

    response.write("RST count      :" & CountCheck)
    response.end
```

The response.end and response.write RST count never get hit, it just keeps looping making the page very slow.

The response.write SQL results in: `SELECT * FROM [qrySnipperKalender_B] WHERE [snipperdag] >= 15281 AND [snipperdag]<= 15355 ORDER BY [FunctieGroep], [Relatienaam], [Datum] ASC`

When I run this query in the SQL server it results in 953 records (like it should).

So the question is, why is this loop broken / keeps it running?

I already tried to modify the loop with the rst.BOF (first I only had the EOF) but this doesn't have any effect. I also tried to use an IF condition inside the loop that if it hits EOF then exit the loop, but this also doesn't work.

Comment: You're not doing anything to advance to the next record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to `rst.MoveNext` within the loop to navigate to the next record

```
Do while not rst.EOF 
    CountCheck = CountCheck + 1
    response.write("Count is: " & CountCheck & "<br>")
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: How stupid of me that I missed that :/ I'm sorry, I'll try to look a bit better next time:) Thank you anyway!

Comment: Like this hasn't been answered before on SO. Working with a Recordset 101.